# HTML5 video autoplay not working in ios 16.3 browser

Tags: angular, html5-video

HTML 5 video tag autoplay is not working for ios 16.3 devices. previously I tried with ios 15 versions, there autoplay is working fine.

I have a video tag in my angular project such as

```
<video id="player" playsinline disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload" [autoplay]='true' [muted]='true' [src]="samplevideo.mp4">
    <source [src]="samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <track label="English" kind="captions" />
</video>
```

This code is working fine in ios 15, 14. But in this particular device 'iphone 11 ios 16.3', autoplay is not working.
I even tried to give this code to initiate play action dynamically

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var video = (document as any).getElementById('player');
  console.log("auto play on");
  video.play();
}, 1000);
```

But still the issue is not fixed. don't know if latest ios versions does not support autoplay at all because I couldn't find any documentation on this.